# How to cast lambda parameters in Optional

Tags: java-8

I have a lambda expression like below. What I want to ask is Is there any easy way or best practice for the casting the lambda parameter(x) to String?

```
Optional.ofNullable(result).isPresent( x-> {
String value = (String) x;
});
```

When I try to change input type like

```
String value = (String) x;
```

I am getting below error;

Inconvertible types; cannot cast the lambda parameter to java.lang.String

Comment: `isPresent()` doesn't accept any parameters. Did you mean `ifPresent()`? And what's the type of `result`? If it's a `String`, `x` is already a `String`. If not, you can't cast it to a `String`, but you can convert it to a `String` with `x.toString()`.

Answer (score 3):

You could do a safe casting:

```
 Optional.of(result)
            .filter(String.class::isInstance) // verify that Object is a String
            .map(String.class::cast) // safely cast to String
            .ifPresent( input-> {
                // now input is a String
    });
```